# Map values of multiple dataframes and fill columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets assume I have the following three dataframes:

**Dataframe 1:**

```
df1 = {'year': ['2010','2012','2014','2015'], 'count': [1,1,1,1]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=df1)
df1 = df1.set_index('year')
df1

year    count
2010    1
2012    1
2014    1
2015    1
```

**Dataframe 2:**

```
df2 = {'year': ['2010','2011','2016','2017'], 'count': [2,1,3,1]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=df2)
df2 = df2.set_index('year')
df2

year    count
2010    2
2011    1
2016    3
2017    1
```

**Dataframe 3:**

```
df3 = {'year': ['2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2017'], 'count': [4,2,5,4,4,1,1]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=df3)
df3 = df3.set_index('year')
df3

year    count
2010    4
2011    2
2012    5
2013    4
2014    4
2015    1
2017    1
```

Now I want to have three dataframes with all the years and counts. For example if `df1` has missing years *2011, 2013, 2016, 2017* then these are added in the index of df1 with counts against each of the new added indexes as 0.

So my output would be something like this for df1:

```
year    count
2010    1
2012    1
2014    1
2015    1
2011    0
2013    0
2016    0
2017    0
```

And similarly for df2 and df3 as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.union.html) with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
idx = df1.index.union(df2.index).union(df3.index)
print (idx)
Index(['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', 
       '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017'], dtype='object', name='year')
```

Another solution:

```
from functools import reduce
idx = reduce(np.union1d,[df1.index, df2.index, df3.index])
print (idx)

['2010' '2011' '2012' '2013' '2014' '2015' '2016' '2017']
```

---

```
df1 = df1.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
print (df1)
      count
year       
2010      1
2011      0
2012      1
2013      0
2014      1
2015      1
2016      0
2017      0
```

```
df2 = df2.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
print (df2)
      count
year       
2010      2
2011      1
2012      0
2013      0
2014      0
2015      0
2016      3
2017      1
```

```
df3 = df3.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
print (df3)
      count
year       
2010      4
2011      2
2012      5
2013      4
2014      4
2015      1
2016      0
2017      1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `reindex` on `all_years` like

```
In [257]: all_years = df1.index | df2.index | df3.index

In [258]: df1.reindex(all_years, fill_value=0)
Out[258]:
      count
year
2010      1
2011      0
2012      1
2013      0
2014      1
2015      1
2016      0
2017      0

In [259]: df2.reindex(all_years, fill_value=0)
Out[259]:
      count
year
2010      2
2011      1
2012      0
2013      0
2014      0
2015      0
2016      3
2017      1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with union you can also use unique i.e

```
idx = pd.Series(np.concatenate([df1.index,df2.index,df3.index])).unique()
# or idx = set(np.concatenate([df1.index,df2.index,df3.index])) 
df1.reindex(idx).fillna(0)

      count
year       
2010    1.0
2012    1.0
2014    1.0
2015    1.0
2011    0.0
2016    0.0
2017    0.0
2013    0.0
```

Comment: plus1, but better is `df1.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)`

Comment: Sir I had the same, it makes all the answer very similar so used `fillna`, I came here with union solution lost it in a second so went to unique.

Answer (score 0):

One can also use iteration:

```
# find missing years:
morelist = [ j            # items which satisfy following criteria
             # list of all numbers converted to strings:
             for j in map(lambda x: str(x), range(2010, 2018, 1))
             if  j not in df1.index  ]      # those not in current index

# create a dataframe to be added:
df2add = pd.DataFrame(data=[0]*len(morelist),   
                      columns=['count'], 
                      index=morelist)

# add new dataframe to original:
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2add]) 

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
      count
2010      1
2012      1
2014      1
2015      1
2011      0
2013      0
2016      0
2017      0
```